# How to visualise data from two variables: optimal response and proportion choosing response?

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a dataset with two variables, one is the optimal response and the other is the proportion choosing that response (number of times chosen).

I would somehow like to compare the two an visually present how close they are.

Is it appropriate to use linear regression?

Here's the data:

```
optimal <- structure(list(Probability = c(0.59, 0.6, 0.55, 0.55, 0.6, 0.58, 
0.67, 0.68, 0.74, 0.33, 0.79, 0.42, 0.84, 0.48, 0.78, 0.4, 0.82, 
0.07, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.96, 0.2), Chosing.colour = c(0.16, 
0.21, 0.26, 0.53, 0.84, 0.89, 0.84, 0.947, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 
0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 0.667, 0.3, 0.667, 0.333, 1, 0.667, 0.667, 
0.583)), .Names = c("Probability", "Chosing.colour"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

or as [csv download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/optimal.csv)

Comment: could you please provide more details about the experimental design?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a scatterplot of the two variables. You could make a QQ plot. Those two come immediately to mind.

As to whether it's appropriate to use linear regression - to do what? Linear regression is not about how close two variables are to one another, it is about how one variable depends on another (or more than one other).

More broadly, I believe you've asked a few questions about these data. But I still don't understand what it is you are trying to do, overall. It looks to me like you  are fishing around for something statistical to do with the data, rather than figuring out first what your goal is, and then figuring out the statistics. Even the variable names; to me, "Optimal choice" means a choice. This cannot be a proportion. It has to be a color.

Comment: +1 QQ-plot is great for comparing the distribution of two variables.